# Struts2 - Nesting <s:property> in a custom tag

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2

I have a custom struts2 tag:

```
<s:myTag myprop="..." >
...
</s:mytag>
```

And, I want to get the value of `myprop` attribute of `myTag` from the `ValueStack`.
Like,

`<s:myTag myprop='<s:property value="name"/>'>`

So, I tried setting the `rtexprvalue` attribute for `myprop` to `true` but, still I am not able to see the `<s:property/>` nested inside the custom tag getting evaluated.

There is no error/exception, its just that the **nested** `<s:property/>` is not getting evaluated.

Can someone help me know how to get this working?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried <s:myTag myprop="%{name}" /> ?

Comment: @BobG, can I access static variables using %{name} notation? I actually want to refer to static variables using s:property value="@some.package.ClassName@FOO_PROPERTY" notation.

Comment: I believe so.  I use constructs like <s:if test="%{var == @Class@Constant}">...</s:if> in my JSPs and they work, so I would expect them to work with your tag as well.

Comment: I'm confused by your example. Is myTag a .tag file or did you create a compiled tag in the same tld as the struts tags?

Comment: I created a "compiled tag" with a separate .tld. Did this help clearing the confusion Steven? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Try**

```
<s:myTag>
    <s:param name="myprop">
        ${name}
    </s:param>
</s:mytag>
```

**OR**

```
<s:myTag>
    <s:param name="myprop" value="name" />
</s:mytag>
```

**OR** (Static Content)

```
<s:myTag>
    <s:param name="myprop">
        <s:property value="@some.package.ClassName@FOO_PROPERTY" />
    </s:param>
</s:mytag>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ischin! I will try the above suggestions and get back.

Comment: No Steven. It did n't work for me. Actually I have some processing which is tied to startTag method and there I am not able to see myprop value set via <s:param>. Also I realized now that doing it via s:param involves changing my .tld to not to keep myprop as a "required" field which I am not loving it.